# Code coverage error : Small variable assignment trigger

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, error

I do have a small trigger written to assign variable on a trigger. This is set a flag that make sure another trigger don't get fired based on variable. But I am having issue with code coverage code. Can anyone help?

Trigger is as below.

```
trigger opportunityProduct on OpportunityLineItem (before update) {
  QueryHelper.OpportunityPartLoRa = false;
}
```

The test class that I wrote is

```
@isTest
private class opportunityProduct_test {

   static testMethod void validateopportunityProduct() {

       Test.StartTest();
       QueryHelper.OpportunityPartLoRa = false;
       System.assertEquals(false, QueryHelper.OpportunityPartLoRa);
       Test.StopTest();
    }

}
```

OK....Now,
Finally this is my test class, but the deployment validation says code coverage is 0% for the trigger

```
@isTest
private class opportunityProduct_test {

static testMethod void validateopportunityProduct() {

    Test.StartTest();
    QueryHelper.OpportunityPartLoRa = false;

    Account acc= new Account(Name = 'testAcc',BillingStreet='testStreet',BillingCity ='tectcity',BillingState='testState',BillingPostalCode='123', BillingCountry='testcountry',Description='testdesc');
    insert acc;

    Opportunity opp= new Opportunity(AccountId=acc.id,Amount=1234.00,Description='testdesc',Name='testOpp',Program_EAU__c = '1', StageName='Prospecting',CloseDate = System.Today());
    insert opp;

    PricebookEntry priceBookEntryNew = new PricebookEntry();
    Product2 product = new Product2();

    PriceBook2 pb2 = new PriceBook2();
    pb2.name = 'GEW Water CMS';
    pb2.isActive=true;
    insert pb2;

    product.name = 'Test';
    product.Item_number__c ='Item12';
    product.Standard_unit_Cost__c = 20;
    insert product;

    priceBookEntryNew.Product2Id = product.Id;
    priceBookEntryNew.PriceBook2Id = pb2.Id;
    priceBookEntryNew.UnitPrice = 20;
    Product2 p = [SELECT Standard_unit_Cost__c FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :product.Id LIMIT 1];
    if (p != null) priceBookEntryNew.UnitPrice = p.Standard_unit_Cost__c;

    priceBookEntryNew.UseStandardPrice = false;
    priceBookEntryNew.isactive = true;
    insert priceBookEntryNew;


    OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
        OpportunityId = opp.Id,
        PricebookEntryId = priceBookEntryNew.Id,
        Quantity = 1,
        UnitPrice = priceBookEntryNew.UnitPrice, 
        ServiceDate = System.today()
    );
    insert oli;

    System.assertEquals(false, QueryHelper.OpportunityPartLoRa);
    Test.StopTest();

}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your test is testing the `QueryHelper` class only.

To test the one line in the trigger (and so meet the trigger coverage requirement), you will need to make the trigger run by updating an `OpportunityLineItem` in a test method. You can set value of `QueryHelper.OpportunityPartLoRa` before the update and assert the changed value after the update.

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger is a **before update** trigger and you are only inserting an Opportunity Line Item.

If you do not have WFR or other processes updating the record on insert then you will have to explicitly execute an update in your test method...

```
insert oli;
update oli;
```

Also make sure you are including the test class in your changeset

As an aside, wrapping the entire code is test.startTest and stop test is *superfluous* and does not really accomplish anything. Suggest that you learn what start and stop test are used for so that you can improve your test class mojo.